# Reading XML from URL and assign it to a list

Tags: c#, xml

http://api.serviceu.com/rest/events/occurrences?orgkey=613dc2ce-0b32-4926-8e7e-33ee279be1cb

i have above xml url that have n number of occurances. I need to read the all occurances and load it into list item. How to do that using xml reader.

```
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(strURL);

 while (reader.Read())
 {

 }
```

for example how can i read CategoryList, ContactEmail, Description for each and every Occurrence.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq2Xml can make the life easier.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("http://api.serviceu.com/rest/events/occurrences?orgkey=613dc2ce-0b32-4926-8e7e-33ee279be1cb");
var list = xDoc.Descendants("Occurrence")
            .Select(o => new Item
            {
                Category = (string)o.Element("CategoryList"),
                EMail = (string)o.Element("ContactEmail"),
                Description = (string)o.Element("Description"),
            })
            .ToList();


public class Item
{
    public string Category;
    public string EMail;
    public string Description;
}
```

Comment: Might be beneficial to call `.Value` on those elements.

Comment: Lb.. how can iassign it to a list instead of array?? something like oChLifeItems.Category = o.Element("CategoryList")

Comment: can we find number of occurence?? the above link that i gave have 99 occurances. So can we find that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8a5e1s5):

```
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("..."))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "CategoryList":
                    var cat = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "ContactEmail":
                    var email = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument) whit `XPath`:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("...");
foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("//CategoryList"))
{
    var cat = node.InnerText;
}

foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("//ContactEmail"))
{
    var email = node.InnerText;
}
```

or Linq-to-Xml as *L.B* mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(strURL);

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch(reader.Name)
         {
            case "ContactEmail":
                  //reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
              break;
             //...
         }
    }
```

I would make a backing class for each collection in the XML document.

Comment: A backing class is creating a class that has properties with the same name and type as the XML.

Comment: hi nick,when using above code I am getting error when I am trying to ContactEmail... the error is like this.. The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type EndElement. Line 1, position 100.

Comment: the code is like this     while (reader.Read())
            {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "CategoryList":
                            var cat = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                            break;
                        case "ContactEmail":
                            var email = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                            break;
                    }
            }

Comment: The code was just a small sample to get you going. There are better more complete answers posted. I suggest you use those.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DataContract(Name = "Occurrence", Namespace = "")]
class Occurrence
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CategoryList { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

```
var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Occurrence>), "Occurrences", "");

List<Occurrence> objects = null;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(strURL))
{
    objects = (List<Occurrence>) ser.ReadObject(reader);
}
```